# JAVA encrypted AES 256 CBC To NODE.JS - Problems to migrate code

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, aes

I have been reading several similar questions and based on that for my initial code. Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work.

```
key="fb52042ada308dd1d4dfd8a3870d5ab5"
iv = "bb8e0b158f57f63dfeea86e24af1abfc"
data = {"MerchantId":"0000000000000001"}
```

Get SHA256 from "data" (dataSha256)

Get encryption from Encrypt dataSha256 + iv + key

Result of Hexa encryption, similar to:
**fd72fcc16b66d04cf0f4dd2265a59eb675103482bae806b405bb85595056f5770b3202b42d42a87b767892591a333eb6b5c9ad3ef34f4d415f8d3bbc3d0f389e2e5b6f7cd915520c7b2c19225680728b**

When migrating the code from Java to Node.js, I don't get similar result. The first problem is that the "iv" should be 16 bytes, however in the code it is 32.

JAVA EXTRACT (original)

```java
        public class AesEncryption implements SymmetricEncryptionComponent {
        Map<String, String> initParams;
        String key, iv;
        String mode, encoding;
        String keyFile;
        String ENCODING = "ISO-8859-1";
    
        public AesEncryption() {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        }
    
        // PARAMETERS INITIALITATION
        public void setInitParams()
        {
        initParams=params;
        key=” 1ea9a91b0ba908b44f598d2822499441”;
        iv= "f20946931dd6e8594dc6f469b5e583ab";
        mode= "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
        encoding= "HEX";
        if(encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("BASE64")&&encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("HEX"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("AES.ENCODING can only be 'HEX' of 'BASE64'")
        }
    
        // INFORMATION CIPHERING return encodeBase24
        public String encrypt(String data) {
        byte[] output = null;
        try {
        byte[] keyBytes = decode(key);
        byte[] input = data.getBytes(ENCODING);
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new 
        IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex(iv.toCharArray()));
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = null;
        keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(mode);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        output = cipher.doFinal(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EncryptionException("Error", e);
        }
        return encode(output);
        }
    
        // INFORMATION ENCODE
        private String encode(byte[] output) {
        if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("BASE64"))
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(output);
        else
        return new String(Hex.encodeHex(output));
        }
    
        // INFORMATION DECODE
        private byte[] decode(String data) throws DecoderException {
        if (data.indexOf("=") > 0 || data.indexOf("+") > 0)
        return Base64.decodeBase64(data);
        else
        return Hex.decodeHex(data.toCharArray());
        }
        }
```

NODE EXTRACT (using crypto-js)

```js
        const cryptojs = require("crypto-js");
        const crypto = require("crypto");
    
        let jsonData = {"MerchantId":"0000000000000001"};
        let key = 'fb52042ada308dd1d4dfd8a3870d5ab5';
        let iv = 'bb8e0b158f57f63dfeea86e24af1abfc';
        const jsonDataSha256 = 
        crypto.createHash('sha256').update(JSON.stringify(jsonData)).digest('hex');
    
        key = cryptojs.enc.Latin1.parse(key); //Convierte hex string -> word array
        iv = cryptojs.enc.Latin1.parse(iv);
        jsonDataSha256Bin = cryptojs.enc.Latin1.parse(jsonDataSha256);   //Convert hex 
        string -> word array
    
        console.log(key);
        console.log(iv);
        console.log(jsonDataSha256);
    
        let encrypted = cryptojs.AES.encrypt(jsonDataSha256Bin, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: cryptojs.mode.CBC,
        padding: cryptojs.pad.Pkcs7,
        });
    
        encrypted = encrypted.toString();
        const salida = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(encrypted).digest('hex');
    
        console.log(`${salida}`);
        //Equals to ce994c4d2b1f398ff0bed22c4b48e1f2170dbf26baf2eaacec96ea6b31667cd6
        //No match to Java output.
```

What will I be doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Both key and IV on Java side are in **hex encoding ** so you need to do the same in Node.js, that way the IV e.g. gets the correct length of 16 bytes.

Comment: I.e. use the Hex encoder of CryptoJS instead of the Latin1 encoder for key and IV. Why do you generate the SHA256 hash of plaintext and ciphertext in the NodeJS code?  This doesn't happen in the Java code. Also, there are other vulnerabilities/bugs in both codes, e.g. unnecessarily used libraries, unreliable functions and inconsistent data.

Comment: Thank you both for responding. I'm new to js so I used CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse() to convert a hexa to binary but I see I'm getting a 32 bit one. Regarding Java, I did not include in the code that the data may or may not be a SHA-256. I will try the recommendations. Again thank you very much for the help.